# Gnuplot error (label has coord of 0) for histogram with logscale

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot an histogram with a Y logscale. Here is my code:

```
input_file  = "io_time.dat"
output_file = "io_time.eps"
set terminal postscript eps size 4.0,3.5 enhanced color font "Helvetica,18" solid
set output output_file
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster errorbars gap 1
set boxwidth 0.8
set logscale y
set ylabel 'I/O Duration (sec)'
set xtics mirror rotate by 45 right
plot input_file u 2:3:4:xtic(1) notitle fs pattern 1 lt 1
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
"io_time.gp", line 11: label has y coord of 0; must be above 0 for log scale!
```

Although it seems unrelated to the content of the data file, this data file (io_time.dat) contains 4 columns: the first one for the label of each box, the second one for the box's height (all values are > 0), and the 3rd and 4th columns contain ylow and yhigh values (also > 0).

I'm using gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 5 installed via MacPort on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

EDIT: After investigation, it appears that a line in my $HOME/.gnuplot configuration file is causing the problem:

```
set label  textcolor rgb text_color font my_font
```

text_color and my_font are defined earlier as follows:

```
text_color = "#000000"
my_font = "Helvetica, 18"
```

Here is also a sample data file:

```
A       50.79841091632843       36.28489899635315       69.23793005943298
B       0.11200199127197266     0.032312870025634766    0.42415809631347656
C       0.10992197990417481     0.0323939323425293      0.41459178924560547
D       0.10762600898742676     0.03207087516784668     0.39806699752807617
E       0.03831331729888916     0.03720998764038086     0.04118704795837402
F       0.043952775001525876    0.04250597953796387     0.04720902442932129
G       0.03883504867553711     0.03631401062011719     0.04176783561706543
```

Comment: Hi! Running v4.6 patchlevel 3 on linux, I get the expected output from your script. Also, I added a row of zeros to my datafile, but gnuplot does not care: Space for the new record is left and the label is printed, but no box is drawn (of course), and also no error message is printed. It really seems that the datafile does not matter. How do you run this code? May be, some old settings are the problem.

Comment: I simply run "gnuplot io_time.gp". I have a .gnuplot file in my $HOME to configure a bunch of things, but never had any problem with it (I've been using a logscale in many other types of plots in the past, but I don't recall ever trying with an histogram). It's on my computer at work so I'll check it (and post it if necessary) tomorrow.

Comment: Then please post also a minimal data set which allows to reproduce the error you're having.

Comment: Ok, I added some precisions (the problem seems to come from a line in my .gnuplot file), and a minimal data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you basically already found the source of your problem: You set a label without giving explicit coordinates, in which case `0,0` is used. And this doesn't work with logarithmic scale. Since the labels are placed only when you `plot`, the line number of the `plot` command is reported.

BTW: Why do you set an empty label inside a configuration file?

Comment: I don't know, I took this configuration file from a website, to enhance my plots. The same line is used for xlabel and ylabel, x2label and y2label. I guess the author of the configuration file wanted to set the color and font of all labels, and then let the gnuplot script define (or overwrite) whatever other parameters the labels should have, whether or not there actually are labels to draw.